# How can i write in an Linq to Xml new Element an dynamic value?

Tags: c#, xml

everyone i have an question on how to write the number of my `Enumerable.Range` inside an `new XElement` i create. I want my  code to put for example the current value of "i" inside the Element just like i'm used to do it with {0} but it doesn't work. I've put some code snipped out of  my programm that should explain  what my problem is.

```
  public static void PLCreate() {
        int zahler = 0;
        XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument( 
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Document",
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new XElement("Hmi.Tag.Tag", new XAttribute("ID", zahler = zahler + 1), new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Tags"),
         new XElement("Name", "HMI_Messages_Modul_Axis_Faults{Here is where i should change}_R"), //Here is where i should change
         new XElement("Name", "HMI_Messages.Modul_Axis_Faults[Here inside also].R"))));}
```

Comment: _i'm used to do it with {0}_ - Did you try this in your code? If so, can you show?

Comment: I'd expect just `$"HMI_Messages_Modul_Axis_Faults{i}_R"` would be fine... or you could use `string.Format` etc. There's nothing special about LINQ to XML here... you're just creating a string using a variable value.

Comment: Thanks both Fabio an Jon for the Answer. When i put only the usual {0} it just prints it out like {0} without putting the i inside. But when i do it with Jons method it works for the [{i}] but when i want that the i is inside an {{i}} then it doesnt work like its an negotiation. Then when i put 3{} it works but it gives me then 2x the curly braces {}. Is there an method to avoid that?

Comment: Oh it does Work when i put 3 curly braces. Then its fine :D Thanks for the help

Comment: @Grover1221: What do you mean by "doesn't work like its a negotiation"? I assumed you wanted a value of "HMI_Messages_Modul_Axis_Faults0", then "HMI_Messages_Modul_Axis_Faults1" etc. It's very hard to help when we don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you'd provided a [mcve] including the desired output, I could have written an answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet You gave the right answer with the first response so i didn't have to give more information. Then i asked and answered my second question myself. I wasn't sure how to put curly braces in curly braces.

Comment: But your "answer" to the question is likely to confuse anyone coming across your question, because *they* won't know (just like *I* didn't know) that your desired XML contained braces. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on asking a good question - and bear in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to help solve your immediate problem, it's to create a repository of useful questions and answers.

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind and try to make my questions and answers clear if anyone in the future gonna have the same problem. Thanks again for taking your time to help me. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Well, you could do that - or you could edit **this** question and answer so they'll be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In Interpolated Strings, the dollar sign ($) is used to tell the C# compiler that the string following it is to be interpreted as an Interpolated String. ***The curly braces encapsulate the values (of the variables) to include in the text.******[Source](http://redspa.uk/blog/post/1029/interpolated-strings-c-sharp#:%7E:text=In%20Interpolated%20Strings%2C%20the%20dollar,to%20include%20in%20the%20text.)

And if you want that the string contains an curly brace, than you have to put 3 of them. Like in my example below.

```
public static void PLCreate() {
        int zahler = 0;
        XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument( 
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Document",
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new XElement("Hmi.Tag.Tag", new XAttribute("ID", zahler = zahler + 1), new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Tags"),
         new XElement("Name", $"HMI_Messages_Modul_Axis_Faults{{{Here is where i should change}}}_R"), //Here is where i should change
         new XElement("Name", $"HMI_Messages.Modul_Axis_Faults[Here inside also].R"))));}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).